# Can I power an Orange PI 5B with a 5V 10A (50W) converter?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amperage, watts

I want to power the Orange PI 5B that has a 5V 4A USB type C power port.

I am converting from a car battery 12V 24V to 5V 10A to supply the Orange PI 5B.

In this configuration, I will have the converter output 5V 10A (50W) supplying the power port USB C 5V 4A (20W).

Is that possible? Is there any risk?

Comment: Sure seems okay. The main risk with having a more powerful power supply than necessary is if you accidentally short-circuit something it can do more damage.